# Getting this error CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path "balance" Calculation does not work correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I have this as a problem before me.

When I run this like this it gives me a positive Response. Without problems.

```
router.post("/us-transfer", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var source_currency = 'NGN';
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var currency = req.body.currency;
    var beneficiary_name = req.body.beneficiary_name;
    var AccountNumber = req.body.AccountNumber;
    var RoutingNumber = req.body.RoutingNumber;
    var SwiftCode = req.body.SwiftCode;
    var BankName = req.body.BankName;
    var BeneficiaryAddress = req.body.BeneficiaryAddress;
    var BeneficiaryCountry = req.body.BeneficiaryCountry;

    url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        amount: amount,
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        beneficiary_name: beneficiary_name,
        meta: [
          {
            AccountNumber: AccountNumber,
            RoutingNumber: RoutingNumber,
            SwiftCode: SwiftCode,
            BankName: BankName,
            BeneficiaryName: beneficiary_name,
            BeneficiaryAddress: BeneficiaryAddress,
            BeneficiaryCountry: BeneficiaryCountry,
          },
        ],
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (json) => {
        const debit = await User.find({ email: req.body.email });
        const debit_balance = debit[0].balance;
        const debit_amt = debit_balance - amount;
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { email: req.body.email },
          { $set: { balance: debit_amt } }
        );

        const transactions = new Trans({
          email: req.body.email,
          narration: narration,
          credit: 0.0,
          debit: amount,
          amount: amount,
        });
        try {
          SendFXTransferNotification(req.body.email, beneficiary_name, amount);
          transactions.save();
          //res.send(savedUser);
          console.log("transaction saved");
        } catch (err) {
          //res.status(400).send(err);
          console.log(err);
        }

        //sendTransferConfirmation(email);
        return res.send({ error: false, data: json, message: "OK" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Now here comes the problem. I write this function to perform Currency Exchange

```
const GetEqCurrency = async (source_currency, destination_currency, amount) => {
  var header = {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization":
      "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
  };

  var url = `https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers/rates?amount=${amount}&destination_currency=${destination_currency}&source_currency=${source_currency}`;

  try{
    const response = await fetch(url, {method: 'GET', headers:header});
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    if(responseJson.message == "Transfer amount fetched"){
      return responseJson.data.source.amount;
    }
  }catch(error)
  {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

And it fires back an error.

If my code looks like this

```
router.post("/us-transfer", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var source_currency = 'NGN';
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var currency = req.body.currency;
    var outAmt = GetEqCurrency(source_currency, req.body.currency, amount); //Added this
    var beneficiary_name = req.body.beneficiary_name;
    var AccountNumber = req.body.AccountNumber;
    var RoutingNumber = req.body.RoutingNumber;
    var SwiftCode = req.body.SwiftCode;
    var BankName = req.body.BankName;
    var BeneficiaryAddress = req.body.BeneficiaryAddress;
    var BeneficiaryCountry = req.body.BeneficiaryCountry;

    url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        amount: outAmt, // used outAmt variable here 
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        beneficiary_name: beneficiary_name,
        meta: [
          {
            AccountNumber: AccountNumber,
            RoutingNumber: RoutingNumber,
            SwiftCode: SwiftCode,
            BankName: BankName,
            BeneficiaryName: beneficiary_name,
            BeneficiaryAddress: BeneficiaryAddress,
            BeneficiaryCountry: BeneficiaryCountry,
          },
        ],
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(async (json) => {
        const debit = await User.find({ email: req.body.email });
        const debit_balance = debit[0].balance;
        const debit_amt = debit_balance - outAmt; // used outAmt variable here
        await User.findOneAndUpdate(
          { email: req.body.email },
          { $set: { balance: debit_amt } }
        );

        const transactions = new Trans({
          email: req.body.email,
          narration: narration,
          credit: 0.0,
          debit: amount,
          amount: amount,
        });
        try {
          SendFXTransferNotification(req.body.email, beneficiary_name, amount);
          transactions.save();
          //res.send(savedUser);
          console.log("transaction saved");
        } catch (err) {
          //res.status(400).send(err);
          console.log(err);
        }

        //sendTransferConfirmation(email);
        return res.send({ error: false, data: json, message: "OK" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

The error looks thus

```
Apr 24 12:00:38 PM  POST /api/user-serv/us-transfer 500 833.426 ms - 148
Apr 24 12:00:38 PM  CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "NaN" (type number) at path "balance"
Apr 24 12:00:38 PM      at model.Query.exec (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4933:21)
Apr 24 12:00:38 PM      at model.Query.Query.then (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:5032:15)
Apr 24 12:00:38 PM      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

What am I not doing rightly? I am not seeing anything that looks more like an Error, but at the same time, it still does not work fine. Sought everything on the internet and it is still not making sense.

**Edit**
Testing on Postman

I do this

```
https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers/rates?amount=1000&destination_currency=USD&source_currency=NGN
```

with Bearer Token Parameter here : `Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X`

I am getting this

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Transfer amount fetched",
    "data": {
        "rate": 793.22026,
        "source": {
            "currency": "NGN",
            "amount": 793220.26
        },
        "destination": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "amount": 1000
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that, if i send the request, I still get the above error? Please assist.

Comment: `const debit = await User.find({ email: req.body.email });
        const debit_balance = debit[0].balance;` Maybe there is no user with such an email. You have no code to handle such a case. In this case there will be an attepmt to set `balance` to `NAN`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work, Did some serious debugging and removing it from a function and making it a straight endpoint function worked for me and saved the day. Thank you everyone.